# Is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> recommended in an XHTML page?

Tags: xml, xhtml

A typical XHTML page looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Am I recommended to insert these two lines before that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="style.css" type="text/css"?>
```

Comment: Why would you want to? For what goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

- The XML declaration isn't useful if you are going to use the default values.
- Applying a stylesheet through an XML mechanism isn't useful in an XHTML document since you are, presumably, targeting web browsers which understand the XHTML mechanisms for loading stylesheets
- They won't have any effect if you serve the document as `text/html` (which you probably are and, if not, probably should be … for that matter, you might as well not use XHTML at all, it is more trouble then it is worth for the vast majority of authors)

Comment: Serving XHTML with text/html isn't really that bad; you just have to avoid shorthand like `<script />`